# Full backup of a HDD with NTFS and EXT partitions using Windows

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, backup, disk-image

Windows can't read EXT, there are some apps to do it but are very limited and I need to do a full backup including the OSes (Windows 7 and Linux Mint) on the disk so it can be run from VirtualBox or re-written back to the HDD if necessary.

Last update destroyed my secondary Linux install so I'm running on Windows now, but could make a third Linux install if necessary/only way to complete the task.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can boot with a Live CD/USB, access the disk where your archives are located and store them in another drive. I reccomend you to use Ubuntu live media for this, because you can access the drives without need to mount them via command-line.

Comment: I need to create a disk image not just copy the files

Comment: In this case you can use [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/), and use it as described [here](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use Clonezilla Live on a USB stick for stuff just like you describe.

It's light and easy to use, and I don't know of anything good enough in windows to get that same job done. You can image the disk, or the partitions separately.

Comment: Single-line answers should be avoided. Can you add more details? Instructions, download link, etc? Explain why it would help